# How to prevent Webpack from spamming the browser console?

Tags: webpack

My browser console is always full of `Webpack` outputs which really feel like "spam" in the sense that it's not useful just utterly annoying and a hindrance for working. Example:

```
[HMR] App is up to date.
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
```

I have a whole screen of those. Any simply way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`clientloglevel`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-clientloglevel) and set it to `none`

> When using inline mode, the console in your DevTools will show you messages e.g. before reloading, before an error or when Hot Module Replacement is enabled. Defaults to info.
>
> devServer.clientLogLevel may be too verbose, you can turn logging off by setting it to 'none'.